# Facebook like for every page of my website- clicking Like should share that particular full url, not just website name

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

i want to integrate facebook like button into my website . My website has multiple pages, with multiple products. At present when a user likes my website, only domain name is getting shared like "http://domainname.com" . But,what i want is, if the url is http://domainname.com/products/5 then , if i click like in that page, in the facebook wall, http://domainname.com/products/5 should be shared . What should i do for that ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use OG meta tags in your page header like,

```
<meta property="og:url" content="${someURL}"/>
```

Where the someURL is your dynamic URL.

Please read this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/) for more details

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer .But still same domain name is being shared . I added <meta property="og:url" content="${someURL}"/> to every page with their respective urls . but still same domain.com is being shared, did i miss anything ? And in the tutorial, it showed some authentication and all, but its just a like button, the user need not be authenticated to like , right ? isnt just adding those meta tags enough ?

Comment: You have to use FB API for same. Please find the graph API of facebook you can find it there

Comment: <a name="fb_share" type="button" share_url="YOUR_URL">

Comment: Please use the Facebook debug tool, it’ll tell you what data Facebook extracts from your pages and how, and will give you hints on what to improve. If you’re still having problems after that, please tell as the actual site address, so we can have a look. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug